# How do I get my route to show up on my map with React Google Maps?

Tags: undefined, react-google-maps

I've successfully been able to render the Markers for react-google-maps, but when I started trying to use DirectionsRenderer, I ran into this 'google is not defined' issue. I scoured StackOverflow and the web in general for solutions to this, anywhere from declaring 'google' as a global to playing around with the withScriptjs syntax, and nothing has worked. I'm running out of ideas. Sidenote: I'm deliberately avoiding using the 'recompose' library from the docs because even the library's author thinks Hooks are better...so idk, maybe give me a solution that doesn't require 'recompose' if possible? Thanks a million.

Here's my code:

```
/* global google */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker, DirectionsRenderer } from 'react-google-maps'
import './App.css'

function MyDirectionsRenderer(props) {
  const [directions, setDirections] = useState(null);
  const { origin, destination, travelMode } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(origin.lat, origin.lng),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(destination.lat, destination.lng),
        travelMode: travelMode
      },
      (result, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          setDirections(result);
        } else {
          console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
        }
      }
    );
  }, [directions, destination.lat, destination.lng, origin.lat, origin.lng, travelMode]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={directions} />}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

class Map extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            directions: null
        }
    }

    render(){
        const MyMapComponent = withGoogleMap(props => {
            return (
            <GoogleMap
                defaultZoom={10}
                defaultCenter={{ lat: 42.681340, lng: -89.026930 }}
            >
                <Marker
                    position = {{lat: 42.681340, lng: -89.026930}}
                />
                <MyDirectionsRenderer
                  origin= {{lat: 42.681339, lng: -89.026932}}
                  destination= {{lat: 28.250200, lng: -82.714080}}
                  travelMode= {google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING}
                />
            </GoogleMap>
            )
        })
        return (
            <MyMapComponent
                loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
                mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default Map
```

Edit: I updated the code here to reflect the current status of the project and any existing problems with it. Currently, the problem is that I can't see the route on my map.

Comment: May be you missed this ` directions={props.directions}` - `{props.directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={props.directions} />}`

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I just tried your suggestion, and the error still comes up. I store the state variable "directions" in the DirectionsRenderer "directions" attribute, so it wouldn't refer to the props.

Comment: I also found out that if I write "window.google..." for all the instances of "google," it gives me a new error: "Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Since ESLint is not aware that the variable `google` is a global,  you can declare a variable you referenced as a global by adding the following to the top of your file:

```
/* global google */
```

then the error `'google' is not defined` should disappear.

And last but not least, the instance of `google.maps.DirectionsService` could be created only *once the Google Maps APIs is loaded*. The following example demonstrates how to accomplish it:

```
<GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={4}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 27.71415, lng: -82.3583 }}
>
    <MyDirectionsRenderer
      origin={{ lat: 27.71415, lng: -82.3583 }}
      destination={{ lat: 42.681339, lng: -89.026932 }}
      travelMode={google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING}
    />
</GoogleMap>
```

where

```
function MyDirectionsRenderer(props) {
  const [directions, setDirections] = useState(null);
  const { origin, destination, travelMode } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(origin.lat, origin.lng),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(destination.lat, destination.lng),
        travelMode: travelMode
      },
      (result, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          setDirections(result);
        } else {
          console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
        }
      }
    );
  }, [directions]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={directions} />}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim! I'm going to try this when I get home from work. I managed to get rid of the "google is not defined" error by doing what you said with the /* global google */ a few days ago, and by using a script tag in my index.html head instead of the withScriptjs() method. But what I have now is an error that tells me my API Key isn't authorized to access the DirectionsService API, even though I have it enabled on the Cloud console for my project.

Comment: So it worked! The error is gone. Somehow I still can't see the route on the map, though. Is there a reason that might be?